# kde start menu flip from search

Tags: linux, kde-4

I am using KDE 4.8.2 and I want to know if there is a simple way to go from the search bar, in the start up menu, to the results. It's really annoying not being able to just press the down key and get to the result.

Example:
I press Alt + F1, I start type what I want, what I want appears but to access I have to use the mouse. How not to use the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This down arrow thing used to work for me earlier and works again since the first beta of KDE 4.9. So you can install the release candidate version of KDE 4.9 or wait until the release on August 1.

You should have specified your distribution. It's possible that this is a Kubuntu-only bug.
So in case you *are* using Kubuntu, only the first beta is available to install ([instructions](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.8.90)), as the later betas and release candidates have been ignored somehow... But I'm using it for a month already and it is very stable.

One more suggestion is to use `krunner` instead (default shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and you can change it). It works better for searching stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using KDE 4.8.4 (Mint) and the same thing happens, but I noticed that if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, KDE selects the first item on the list and then I can use <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd>.

Not the best way, but it works.